# Get Uri from drawable resource for Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase-storage, uri, android-drawable, android-resources

You can get your drawable resource Uri with this

```
Uri.Builder().scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
             .authority(resources.getResourcePackageName(R.drawable.ic_user))
             .appendPath(resources.getResourceTypeName(R.drawable.ic_user))
             .appendPath(resources.getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.ic_user))
             .build()
```

This will return `android.resource://com.myapp.sample/drawable/ic_user` but it seems Firebase Storage does not accept Uri like this, only `file:///data/data/com.sample.app/cache/cropped-1168776960.jpg`. As much as possible I do not want to use Bitmap if Uri is available since it is prone to OOM. Any other way to get Uri of drawable resource that is in `file:///` scheme?

Check more about the issue in [repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3121)

Comment: No. Not like that. But copy the resource to file and use the copy.

Comment: @blackapps you mean `Uri.fromFile(File(uri.toString()))`?

Comment: No. That is nonse. I said copy.

Comment: @blackapps, care to give your full answer?

Comment: I already did: `copy the resource to file and use the copy. `

Comment: It is safe to always just comment rather than a proper answer to avoid downvotes? I see. Anyway you mean literally copy it, create a file and save in the app directory then access and get the Uri from there?

Comment: Very well indeed.

Comment: @blackapps hard pass on that solution as it is too busy work just for a Uri, anyway thanks.